# Construct a list of equations using And[]

Tags: list-manipulation

I have for instance the following list of equations:

```
{v1 - x1 - x2 == 0, 1 - E^-x2 + u == 0, v1 - v2 + x1 == 0}
```

I would like to obtain this:

```
v1 - x1 - x2 == 0 && 1 - E^-x2 + u == 0 && v1 - v2 + x1 == 0
```

How can I do this? I've tried:

```
And[{v1 - x1 - x2 == 0, 1 - E^-x2 + u == 0, v1 - v2 + x1 == 0}]
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
{v1 - x1 - x2 == 0, 1 - E^-x2 + u == 0, v1 - v2 + x1 == 0} /. 
 List -> And

(* v1 - x1 - x2 == 0 && 1 - E^-x2 + u == 0 && v1 - v2 + x1 == 0  *)
```

or this:

```
And @@ {v1 - x1 - x2 == 0, 1 - E^-x2 + u == 0, v1 - v2 + x1 == 0}

v1 - x1 - x2 == 0 && 1 - E^-x2 + u == 0 && v1 - v2 + x1 == 0
```

Have fun!